# How do I automatically create images in HTML or Javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, webforms

I am prepared to take hits on this question, because I don't even know how to go about researching this.  I did try, don't get me wrong. Maybe someone can tell me what it would even be called.  Anyways, I have an .htm file and am passing a variable to it like

```
Response.Redirect("multiImage.htm?val1=2");
```

I want to generate val1 many images. so in this example, val1=2, so 2 images generated.  I'm not very skilled with html or javascript and this is what I have so far:

```
<!--When a new camera is added, one needs to change the bound in the for loop in the javascript function in part a.
Then add a new image in part b.-->

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>

<!--********************************Part a**********************************-->
    <title>Cameras</title>
    <script type="text/javascript" language="JavaScript">
        var num = '<%= Request.QueryString("val1") %>';
        function refreshIt() {
            if (!document.images) return;
            for (var i = 1; i <= num; i++) {
                document.getElementById("imgcontainer" + i).src = "/Imghandler2.ashx?id=" + i + "&rand=" + Math.random();
            }
            setTimeout('refreshIt()', 1000);
        }
    </script>
</head>
<!--********************************Part b**********************************-->
    <body onload="setTimeout('refreshIt()',1000)">
        <table>
            <tr>
```

That part works, and so does this:

```
<!--                <td><img id="imgcontainer1" src="/Imghandler2.ashx?id=1" alt="cam image" /></td>
                <td><img id="imgcontainer2" src="/Imghandler2.ashx?id=2" alt="cam image" /></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td><img id="imgcontainer3" src="/Imghandler2.ashx?id=3" alt="cam image" /></td>
                <td><img id="imgcontainer4" src="/Imghandler2.ashx?id=4" alt="cam image" /></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td><img id="imgcontainer5" src="/Imghandler2.ashx?id=5" alt="cam image" /></td>
                <td><img id="imgcontainer6" src="/Imghandler2.ashx?id=6" alt="cam image" /></td>-->
```

But I have commented the above out, because I want to auto generate that.  Something like this below.  And I know this doesn't work, but hopefully it will give an idea of what I'm trying to do:

```
                    <script type="text/javascript" language="JavaScript">
                        var num = '<%= Request.QueryString("val1") %>';
                        for (var i = 1; i <= num; i++) {
                        document.write('<tr>')
                        document.write('<img id="imgcontainer[i+1]" src="/Imghandler2.ashx?id=[i+1]" alt="cam image" />')
                        document.write('</tr>')

                        }
                    </script>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </body>
</html>
```

Like I said, I don't even know how I would go about researching this.  I did try, but didn't find what I needed.  Is this even possible?

Comment: What environment are you running it from?

Comment: Visual Studio 2010, is that what you mean?

Comment: I actually meant web-server vs. stand-alone.

Comment: Right now I'm just testing it on my computer, but it's eventually going to be on a web-server.

Answer (score 0):

After more research I found out how to do this.  Here is my full html code:

```
<!--This .htm file creates an img for the image to be displayed.  The number img's created is equal to the number
of cameras selected in "Main.aspx"-->

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>


    <title>Cameras</title>


<script src="Scripts/jquery-1.4.1.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

<!--*************************beginning of javascript code******************************-->
    <script type="text/javascript" language="JavaScript">

// Function gets the parameter values in the url string.
        function getParameterByName(name) {
            name = name.replace(/[\[]/, "\\[").replace(/[\]]/, "\\]");
            var regex = new RegExp("[\\?&]" + name + "=([^&#]*)"),
        results = regex.exec(location.search);
            return results === null ? "" : decodeURIComponent(results[1].replace(/\+/g, " "));
        }

// Function programmatically creates a new img for each camera selected in Main.aspx.
        function add() {

            for (var i = 1; i <= getParameterByName('val1'); i++) {

                var element = document.createElement("img");
                element.setAttribute("id", "imgcontainer" + i.toString());
                element.setAttribute("src", "/Imghandler2.ashx?id=" + i.toString());
                element.setAttribute("alt", "cam image");
                document.getElementById("table1").appendChild(element);
                        }
            }

// Function updates each image in each img
        function refreshIt() {
            if (!document.images) return;
            for (var i = 1; i <= getParameterByName('val1'); i++) {
                document.getElementById("imgcontainer" + i).src = "/Imghandler2.ashx?id=" + i + "&rand=" + Math.random();
            }
            setTimeout('refreshIt()', 1000);
        }
    </script>
<!--*************************end of javascript code******************************-->
</head>

    <body onload="add(); setTimeout('refreshIt()',1000);">
        <table id="table1">


        </table>
    </body>
</html>
```